# Displaying an unknown amount of images in WPF without losing smooth scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, image, scrollviewer

I'm trying to code a picture book. For this I am scanning every subfolder of the MyPictures Folder and add every picture I find to an observableCollection. I dont want to limit the amount of pictures, in this view.
In function it should work the same way, the normal Windows explorer window with extra big symbols does.

I have tried a lot of things, but every solution I found always had the problem that I lost smooth scrolling (I tried virtualizing stackpanel. Aside from the worse looks compared to a grid it also had the scrolling problems).
If I understood correctly, the smooth scrolling doesn't work anymore, because pictures are loaded, and the scrollviewer has to be updatet, regardless if it is a virtualizing stackpanel or not.
In the windows explorer this is worked around by displaying placeholders, I think.

Do you have any idea how I could implement something like that myself?

Edit: At the moment, I am preloading chunks of the pictures. When the view was scrolled down, I update that chunk with the new pictures. But while the update is running, the scrolling gets laggy again.

Comment: If you're adding the pictures one by one to the collection, you might try adding them in large batches to smooth it out a bit.

Comment: I have tried that already. Sadly the scrollviewer still gets updatet one picture at a time, just faster cause the pictures have already been loaded. the scrolling problem is still there

Comment: You could add all of the pictures to the collection before displaying, but that might not be what you want.

Comment: I also tried that. it produces really long loading times, before anything gets displayed. When all pictures are loaded it runs smooth, but if there are 10.000+ pictures in the folder it takes up a lot of time.
Also, this would be a terrible strain on the memory.
At the moment, I am preloading chunks of the pictures. When the view was scrolled down, I update that chunk with the new pictures. But while the update is running, the scrolling gets laggy again.

Comment: have you tried decodepixel width and height? or the image cache mode?

Comment: I have tried it and it helps with the load times. But the scrollviewer still gets updatet, which results in lag.